# I'm making a simple Login system using hashed password and session. Login page doesn't recognize Hash from different register page

Tags: php

I'm making a simple Login system using a hashed password and session, the hashed password is being set in another page. How can I make the code recognize the hash which is set in another page?

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $servername = "localhost";
    $dbusername = "root";
    $dbpassword = "";
    $dbname = "usersystem";

    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $dbusername, $dbpassword, $dbname);

    $Username = $_POST["Username"];
    $Password = $_POST["Password"];

    $_SESSION['user'] = "";
    $hash = password_hash($Password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE Username = '$Username'";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            if (password_verify($Password, $hash)) {
                $_SESSION['user'] = $_POST["Username"];
                echo($_SESSION['user']);
            }
            else {
                echo("Incorrect Username");
            }
        }
        else {
            echo("Incorrect Password");
        }
    $conn->close();
?>
```

---

The register page where the data is inserted into the database:

```
<?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $dbusername = "root";
    $dbpassword = "";
    $dbname = "usersystem";

    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $dbusername, $dbpassword, $dbname); 

    $Username = $_POST["usrnm"];
    $Password = $_POST["psw"];

    $hash = password_hash($Password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO users (Username, Password) VALUES ('$Username', '$hash')";

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "New record created successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }



    $conn->close();
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider what you're doing here:

```
password_verify($Password, $hash)
```

Where do your `$Password` and `$hash` values come from?

```
$Password = $_POST["Password"];
$hash = password_hash($Password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
```

They both come from the user input.  So nowhere are you checking if the entered password matches what's in the database.  You're checking if the entered password matches *itself*.  This will *always* be true.

When checking an entered password, you don't need to hash it.  You need to use `password_verify` to compare it to the *stored* hash.  Something like this:

```
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
if (password_verify($Password, $row["Password"])) {
```

---

Side note: Be aware that your code is wide open to [**SQL injection**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php).  This is not only a glaring security problem but also a very common source of bugs.  There are some great [explanations and examples here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) to help you correct this.

Comment: Yes I am aware of the threat to an SQL Injection, but I wanted to teach myself the basics of hashing and Session's first, now I will read about how to protect yourself against such an attack, quick question though, do the placement and usage of the **$_SESSION** make sense? Since i'm kinda new to this stuff I'm not really sure how to use it. But thanks for the answer btw.